# How to save pycharm theme?

Tags: pycharm

Finally I got pycharm working with all my projects. I edited the default dracula theme and it turned out pretty good.
Now I would like to "save it out" so that I can use the same theme on my other machine.

How can I accomplish that? I have tried to copy the file from pycharm/colors directory as well as using the File->Export Settings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the pointers on twitter I was able to figure out.
Here are the steps:

1. Under File select Export Settings
2. Click Select None
3. Check Look and Feel and Editor Colors
4. Click OK to save it

This saves a settings.jar file. I opened this jar file and my theme was in colors folder :)